# Values Inexplicably multiplying by a power of 15 when performing a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I started building a query that joins 5 separate tables together to get values to multiply and sum. However, I seem to be facing a rather odd issue. Whenever I attempt to join a certain table to my query, suddenly all of my values are multiplied by 15, the counts, the sums, etc. I'm trying to figure out what is causing all these extra runs. Any ideas?

Full Query

```
USE Facilities_Database
DECLARE @minimumDate DATE
DECLARE @maximumDate DATE

SET @minimumDate = '2014/12/11'
SET @maximumDate = '2014/12/15' 

SELECT  tab4.TypeName AS 'Labor Type'
        ,tab1.Building
        ,CAST(@minimumDate AS nvarchar(255)) +  ' - ' + CAST(@maximumDate AS nvarchar(255)) AS 'Date Range'
        ,Count(tab1.CHSRNumber) AS 'Number of CHSRs'
        ,ISNULL(SUM(tab5.[Item Cost] * tab3.[Amount Used]),0) AS 'Total Material Cost'
        ,ISNULL(SUM(tab2.[Hour Worked] * tab2.[Hourly CHSR Labor Rate]),0) AS 'Total Labor Cost'
FROM    [Facilities].[HardwareSupportRequest] tab1
    JOIN Facilities.tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR tab2
        ON tab1.CHSRNumber = tab2.[CHSR #]
    JOIN Facilities.tblMaterialUsed tab3
        ON tab1.CHSRNumber = tab3.[CHSR #]
    JOIN Facilities.LaborTypes tab4
        ON tab2.LaborTypeId = tab4.Id
    JOIN Facilities.tblMaterial tab5
        ON tab3.MaterialId = tab5.Id
WHERE tab1.ActualCompleteDate BETWEEN @minimumDate AND @maximumDate AND tab4.TypeName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    tab4.TypeName,Building
ORDER BY    Building,tab4.TypeName
```

Working Query:

```
USE Facilities_Database
SELECT  tab1.Building
        ,COUNT(*) AS 'CHSR Count'
        ,SUM(tab2.[Hour Worked] * 40) AS 'Labor Cost'
    FROM [Facilities].[HardwareSupportRequest] tab1
    INNER JOIN Facilities.tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR tab2 ON
        tab1.CHSRNumber = tab2.[CHSR #]
    INNER JOIN Facilities.LaborTypes tab3 ON
        tab2.LaborTypeId = tab3.Id
    --INNER JOIN Facilities.tblMaterialUsed tab4 ON
        --tab4.[CHSR #] = tab1.CHSRNumber
    --INNER JOIN Facilities.tblMaterial tab5 ON
    --  tab4.MaterialId = tab5.Id
    WHERE ActualCompleteDate BETWEEN '2014/12/11' AND '2014/12/15'
    GROUP BY tab1.Building,tab3.TypeName
```

The table that causes the problems is `tblMaterialsUsed`.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Check the full result (without the sum and count and the grouping) the query returns when joining to `tblMaterialsUsed`. It's most likely that the join to that table is returning 15 results per row of the other tables.

Comment: This appears to be correct, how can I sum all of the materials so that they are returned properly?

Comment: Jdsfighter: I have already answered the question of how to do this correctly. I have even provided the query to do it. Is something not working or are you not seeing the updates?

Comment: Your query was not working, I modified my own code, and I'm now getting the correct values it appears.

Comment: Did you use my revised query with 2 CTEs or the original with just 1? Also, why didn't you comment on my answer that it wasn't working?

Comment: I can try it again, and see, but my main issue is that ultimately, this will be used in a view, and I cannot use CTEs in a view (I think).

Comment: @Jdsfighter You didn't say you needed this in a View in the question. But if you do, then how are you planning on getting the `@minimumDate` and `@maximumDate` variables in there? That requires an inline TVF, which will accept CTEs.

Comment: I actually only had those in for testing purposes so I could quickly swap them in a single place.

Comment: But you don't have to only have those for testing. You _should_ have those via an inline TVF so you don't always pull ALL data just to filter afterwards..

Comment: An Inline Table-Valued function is a View that accepts parameters, so you can keep the exact same query and have it be even more efficient as you can pre-filter some of the data. I have updated my answer with the few minor changes to make to get that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding a JOIN multiplies the results of GROUP BY operations, then the JOIN is returning more than 1 row per JOIN criteria. Either narrow it down (maybe you are missing 1 or more JOIN fields?) or add more fields to the GROUP BY to change the granularity of what is being aggregated.

The issue is that you have a list of Materials User per each `[CHSR #]`. Those rows cause a "Cartesian Product" such that the other rows are duplicated per each row in `tblMaterialUsed`. Hence the Total `Material Cost` field was probably correct while the `Number of CHSRs` and `Total Labor Cost` were multiplied. Essentially, you need to group data at the same level of granularity, which means 1-to-1 across `CHSRNumber` / `[CHSR #]`

The following should solve this issue. If it doesn't, that would be due to more than 1 row per `CHSRNumber` / `[CHSR #]` in the main query (which is getting JOINed with the 1 row per `CHSRNumber` / `[CHSR #]` of the `material` CTE). In this case, you would apply the same theory to the main query by creating a second CTE for that aggregation and then just JOIN both of those results in the new main query. (and I have updated the query below to incorporate that change as it is doubtful that it wouldn't be needed)

```sql
;WITH material AS
(
  SELECT mu.[CHSR #],
         ISNULL(SUM(mtrl.[Item Cost] * mu.[Amount Used]),0) AS [MaterialCost]
  FROM   Facilities.tblMaterialUsed mu
  INNER JOIN Facilities.tblMaterial mtrl
          ON mu.MaterialId = mtrl.Id
  GROUP BY mu.[CHSR #]
), labour AS
(
  SELECT tab1.CHSRNumber,
         tab4.TypeName,
         tab1.Building,
         ISNULL(SUM(tab2.[Hour Worked] * tab2.[Hourly CHSR Labor Rate]),0) AS [LaborCost]
  FROM   [Facilities].[HardwareSupportRequest] tab1
  JOIN   Facilities.tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR tab2
     ON tab1.CHSRNumber = tab2.[CHSR #]
  JOIN Facilities.LaborTypes tab4
     ON tab2.LaborTypeId = tab4.Id
  WHERE tab1.ActualCompleteDate BETWEEN @minimumDate AND @maximumDate
  AND   tab4.TypeName IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY    tab1.CHSRNumber, tab4.TypeName, tab1.Building
)
SELECT  labour.TypeName AS [Labor Type],
        labour.Building,
        CAST(@minimumDate AS NVARCHAR(255)) +  ' - '
           + CAST(@maximumDate AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS [Date Range],
        COUNT(labour.[CHSRNumber]) AS [Number of CHSRs],
        SUM(material.[MaterialCost]) AS [Total Material Cost],
        SUM(labour.[LaborCost]) AS [Total Labor Cost]
FROM    labour
INNER JOIN material
        ON labour.CHSRNumber = material.[CHSR #]
GROUP BY  labour.TypeName, labour.Building
ORDER BY  labour.Building, labour.TypeName;
```

If you want this in a View, instead use an Inline Table-Valued Functions by adding the following to the beginning:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCosts (@minimumDate DATE, @maximumDate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
```

And

- remove the `;` before the `;WITH`
- remove the `ORDER BY`

---

Also, it would be a huge benefit if you used acronyms for table aliases instead of `tab1`, `tab2`, etc as it would make the query *much* easier to read, especially given that the same table in both queries isn't even the same `tab#`.

Comment: Well the goal is to sum all of the labor and materials. Per individual chsr number.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Exactly. Please see my update for the explanation.

Comment: @Jdsfighter I went ahead and applied the same theory to the labour calculations. Please see the updated answer that now has 2 CTEs to normalize both sides to having a single `CHSRNumber` / `[CHSR #]` each.

Comment: I receive an error: `Column 'Facilities.HardwareSupportRequest.CHSRNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Jdsfighter that error has been fixed. Please see the update.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Updated again to show how it can be used in an inline TVF, which is a View that accepts parameters.

Comment: This doesn't group the values properly. It should be summing all of the labor and materials into a single row for each LaborType within each Building.

Comment: I corrected your code by adding a group by in the very bottom select. Your results return identical to my above query in my answer.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Is a `[CHSR #]` specific to a Building and LaborType or does it span multiple Building / LaborType combinations?

Comment: @Jdsfighter Yes, I just saw that I had removed the GROUP BY from the main query.  I will add that back in.

Comment: A CHSR is a `Computer Hardware Service Request`, it is essentially a work order. It is specific to a building, but can have multiple LaborTypes.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Ok. I have fixed my query (for good this time :). And having multiple `LaborType`s per `CHSR` is what I have been trying to warn you and HartCo about. If there are 2 `LaborType`s per a CHSR, it will mulitply the `MaterialCost` by 2. Remember that the JOIN of the `tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR` table happens _before_ the `GROUP BY`, hence the `MaterialCost` row will be applied to each of the `LaborType` rows of that matching `CHSR#`. But you won't see this problem for CHSR's that only have a single LaborType.

Comment: Well it appears I'm still having issues with this query as I can't quite get the numbers to cooperate. I may have to take an entirely different approach. (My query is failing too)

Comment: @Jdsfighter Can you be more explicit? It is hard to help when given a vague "numbers don't work". Is it possible for a CHSR to have one cost and not the other? If so we need to use LEFT JOINs instead of INNER. I have been wondering about that possibility. but that would be easy to fix once I know if one (or both) can be "empty" for a particular CHSR.

Comment: It's a difficult concept to explain. Imagine that a `CHSR`  is a work request. For each `CHSR` we will have multiple different labor records (and labor types). We will also have many different materials. However, the main `CHSR` table also has a row called WorkType, and it will often be: Install, Removal, Etc. I need to group certain LaborTypes together, and explicitly print out others. This may require many many queries.

Comment: @Jdsfighter might just require a CASE statement in the GROUP BY. But right now I don't have enough info to go on. Still need to know if a CHSR can have a Labor cost but no Material Cost.

Comment: I am writing a view to generate a report off of. For WorkType (Install and Removal), I need to track the materials. If the labor type is Install, Build, or Testing they should be in one row, however they shouldn't sum all of the materials (as it will triple them), but they should sum their labors (because they'll be different). IT's a very badly designed system that I was thrust into.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Collapsing LaborTypes of Install, Build, and Testing into a single row with aggregated LaborCost could probably be done in the "labor" CTE using a CASE statement on LaborTypeID. That would be duplicated in the SELECT within that CTE and you need to give a new name to that combined entry. But again, if it is possible to have no MaterialCost entries, that has to be confirmed so that the JOIN to that CTE can be made a LEFT JOIN so as to not exclude Labor records.

Comment: I started a new question that is specifically geared toward what I am after > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441790/create-a-view-that-groups-some-data-but-doesnt-group-other-data

Answer (score 1):

You've got insufficient `JOIN` criteria resulting in one row joining to multiple rows.

If the following query results in two different numbers, then you know that `JOIN` is to blame:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(DISTINCT [CHSR #])
FROM Facilities.tblMaterialUsed
```

You need to then determine how to exclude the extra records by adding to your `JOIN` criteria or perhaps aggregating in a subquery first.

**Update**:
To aggregate first you can use a `cte` or subquery to aggregate by `CHSR #` then join to that cte/subquery:

```
;WITH Materials AS (SELECT mat.[CHSR #]
                          ,ISNULL(SUM(tab5.[Item Cost] * tab3.[Amount Used]),0) AS Total_Material_Cost                  
                    FROM Facilities.tblMaterialUsed tab3
                    JOIN Facilities.tblMaterial tab5
                      ON tab3.MaterialId = tab5.Id
                    GROUP BY mat.[CHSR #]
                    )
SELECT  tab4.TypeName AS 'Labor Type'
        ,tab1.Building
        ,CAST(@minimumDate AS nvarchar(255)) +  ' - ' + CAST(@maximumDate AS nvarchar(255)) AS 'Date Range'
        ,Count(tab1.CHSRNumber) AS 'Number of CHSRs'
        ,SUM(mat.Total_Material_Cost) AS 'Total Material Cost'
        ,ISNULL(SUM(tab2.[Hour Worked] * tab2.[Hourly CHSR Labor Rate]),0) AS 'Total Labor Cost'
FROM    [Facilities].[HardwareSupportRequest] tab1
    JOIN Facilities.tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR tab2
        ON tab1.CHSRNumber = tab2.[CHSR #]
    JOIN Facilities.LaborTypes tab4
        ON tab2.LaborTypeId = tab4.Id
    JOIN Materials mat
        ON tab1.CHSRNumber = mat.[CHSR #]
WHERE tab1.ActualCompleteDate BETWEEN @minimumDate AND @maximumDate AND tab4.TypeName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    tab4.TypeName,Building
ORDER BY    Building,tab4.TypeName
```

Comment: The numbers are in fact different, but this is somewhat to be expected. There are many different materials used for each individual CHSR. How could I group and sum all of the materials for each CHSR so that this displays accurately?

Comment: @Jdsfighter You'd use a `cte` or a subquery to aggregate those first, then join to that cte/subquery, see update.

Comment: @Jdsfighter and HartCo, as I explained in a comment on Jdsfighter's answer: This actually does not work. It suffers from the same problem that the original query has, just reversed such that now the subquery values (i.e. `mat.Total_Material_Cost`) will be multiplied by the number of rows of the outer query, per each `[CHSR #]`. And I assume that there are multiple rows per `[CHSR #]` in the `tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR` table, each with their own `LaborTypeId`. Technically you could probably get away with using `MAX` instead of `SUM` for `mat.Total_Material_Cost` but that is an error-prone hack.

Comment: Actually @srutzky, my query is now showing the proper amounts. I went back and manually checked it against several of our other reports and it is identical.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I can use subqueries to fix this issue

```
USE Facilities_Database
DECLARE @minimumDate DATE
DECLARE @maximumDate DATE

SET @minimumDate = '2012/12/11'
SET @maximumDate = '2014/12/15' 

SELECT  LaborTypes.TypeName AS 'Labor Type'
        ,CHSRs.Building
        ,CAST(@minimumDate AS nvarchar(255)) +  ' - ' + CAST(@maximumDate AS nvarchar(255)) AS 'Date Range'
        ,Count(CHSRs.CHSRNumber) AS 'Number of CHSRs'
        ,ISNULL(SUM(matUsed.cost),0) AS 'Total Material Cost'
        ,ISNULL(SUM(Labor.[Hour Worked] * Labor.[Hourly CHSR Labor Rate]),0) AS 'Total Labor Cost'
FROM    [Facilities].[HardwareSupportRequest] CHSRs
    JOIN Facilities.tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR Labor
        ON CHSRs.CHSRNumber = Labor.[CHSR #]
    JOIN (SELECT ROUND(SUM(matU.[Amount Used] * mat.[Item Cost] * 1.05417 * 1.15),2) AS cost, [CHSR #]
        FROM Facilities.tblMaterialUsed matU
        JOIN Facilities.tblMaterial mat ON
        matU.MaterialId = mat.Id
        GROUP BY matU.[CHSR #]) matUsed ON
        matUsed.[CHSR #] = CHSRs.CHSRNumber
    --JOIN Facilities.tblMaterialUsed tab3
    --  ON CHSRs.CHSRNumber = tab3.[CHSR #]
    JOIN Facilities.LaborTypes LaborTypes
        ON Labor.LaborTypeId = LaborTypes.Id
    --JOIN Facilities.tblMaterial tab5
    --  ON tab3.MaterialId = tab5.Id
WHERE CHSRs.ActualCompleteDate BETWEEN @minimumDate AND @maximumDate AND LaborTypes.TypeName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    LaborTypes.TypeName,Building
ORDER BY    Building,LaborTypes.TypeName
```

Comment: This actually does not work. It suffers from the same problem that you originally had, just reversed such that now your subquery values (i.e. `matUsed.cost`) will be multiplied by the number of rows of the outer query, per each `[CHSR #]`. And I assume that you do have multiple rows per `[CHSR #]` in the `tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR` table, each with their own `LaborTypeId`. Hence my answer is the only correct one, even if you convert the CTEs into a subqueries.