# Create a view that groups some data, but doesn't group other data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am attempting to write a query to populate a report.

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/920eb

The query relies on several different tables

```
HardwareSupportRequest
tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR
LaborTypes
tblMaterialUsed
tblMaterial
```

Inside of `HardwareSupportRequest`, I have a huge array of fields, but the pertinent ones are

```
CHSRNumber - Basically the ID/unique identifier
Building - Used for grouping by location
WorkType - Can be 'Electric Install','Electric Removal', if it's something else, it'll be ignored and a differ field will be used to group.
```

Inside of `tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR` the fields are

```
[CHSR#] - fk
[Hours Worked]
[Hourly CHSR Labor Rate]
LaborTypeId
```

Inside of 'tblCHSRLabor`

```
id
LaborType
```

Inside of `tblMaterialUsed`

```
MaterialId -fk
[CHSR#] - fk
[Amount Used]
```

Inside of 'tblMaterial'

```
id - pk
[Item Cost]
```

I need a method of generating a view that does some rather complex operations. First, if the LaborType of a record is `Install`, `Testing`, or `Build`. They must be treated as a single row (for labor cost). Any other LaborType will have its own row.

It needs to be grouped by `Building` and `LaborType`. I also have to count how many CHSRs there are for each record.

I am so beyond lost at this point that I'm bashing my head against the keyboard. Every method I have tried has either failed or had the high-ups shake their head at it.

My most recent attempt:

```
USE Facilities_Database
DECLARE @minimumDate DATE
DECLARE @maximumDate DATE

SET @minimumDate = '2014/12/11'
SET @maximumDate = '2014/12/15' 

SELECT  CHSRs.WorkType
        ,LaborTypes.TypeName AS 'Labor Type'
        ,CHSRs.Building
        ,CHSRNumber
        ,Count(CHSRs.CHSRNumber) AS 'Number of CHSRs'
        ,ISNULL(SUM(matUsed.cost),0) AS 'Total Material Cost'
        ,ISNULL(SUM(Labor.[Hour Worked] * Labor.[Hourly CHSR Labor Rate]),0) AS 'Total Labor Cost'
FROM    [Facilities].[HardwareSupportRequest] CHSRs
    JOIN Facilities.tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR Labor
        ON CHSRs.CHSRNumber = Labor.[CHSR #]
    JOIN (SELECT ROUND(SUM(matU.[Amount Used] * mat.[Item Cost] * 1.05417 * 1.15),2) AS cost, [CHSR #]
        FROM Facilities.tblMaterialUsed matU
        JOIN Facilities.tblMaterial mat ON
        matU.MaterialId = mat.Id
        GROUP BY matU.[CHSR #]) matUsed ON
        matUsed.[CHSR #] = CHSRs.CHSRNumber
    JOIN Facilities.LaborTypes LaborTypes
        ON Labor.LaborTypeId = LaborTypes.Id
WHERE CHSRs.ActualCompleteDate BETWEEN @minimumDate AND @maximumDate AND LaborTypes.TypeName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    CHSRs.CHSRNumber,CHSRs.WorkType,LaborTypes.TypeName,Building
ORDER BY    ChsrNumber,Building,LaborTypes.TypeName
```

Example SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/920eb

**EDIT**

An example output would look something similar to

```
Building    LaborType   NumberOfCHSRs   MaterialCost    LaborCost
D2          Admin       6               0               300
D2          Install     20              10349.42        32400
D2          Removal     2               350.42          1000
D2          Database    4               0               22000
...
```

It's very important to note that the materials are linked to a CHSR, but they should only be summed for Installs and Removals.

Comment: How about instead of text explanations of your tables you post actual ddl and sample data. sqlfiddle.com is an excellent location for this.

Comment: Fiddle added http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/758cd

Comment: Your fiddle is setup for mysql but you have tagged your question with sql-server. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Oh dear, you're correct. I'm on MSSQL

Comment: Corrected fiddle > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/920eb

Comment: OK cool. Now what should the output be based on your sample data?

Comment: @Jdsfighter Look at this SQL Fiddle please. Is this what you want? If it is I'll write it up as an answer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/920eb/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly have a lot of test data, but it is too narrow. It would have been better to have only a couple of CHSR entries and a lot of different LaborTypes used rather than all *Electric Install*s. So I didn't do a whole lot of testing. But this looks like it will get you pretty close to what you want:

```
select  hsr.Building,
        case when lt.TypeName in( 'Install', 'Testing', 'Build' )
             then 'Labor'
             else lt.TypeName end as LaborType,
        hsr.CHSRNumber,
        Count( * ) as [Number of CHSRs],
        Cast( Sum( case when lt.TypeName in( 'Install', 'Removal' )
                        then mu.[Amount Used] * mat.[Item Cost] * 1.2122955
                        else 0 end
                 ) as Money )as MaterialCost,
        Cast( Sum( lpc.[Hour Worked] * lpc.[Hourly CHSR Labor Rate] )as Money )as LaborCost
from    HardwareSupportRequest hsr
join    tblCHSRLaborPerCHSR    lpc
    on  lpc.CHSR = hsr.CHSRNumber
join    LaborTypes             lt
    on  lt.ID    = lpc.LaborTypeID
join    tblMaterialUsed        mu
    on  mu.CHSR  = hsr.CHSRNumber
join    tblMaterial            mat
    on  mat.Id = mu.MaterialId
where   hsr.ActualCompleteDate BETWEEN @minimumDate AND @maximumDate
group by hsr.Building,
         case when lt.TypeName in( 'Install', 'Testing', 'Build' )
              then 'Labor'
              else lt.TypeName end,
         hsr.CHSRNumber;
```

You wanted to merge the rows with labor types Install, Testing and Build, so that is what the `case` statements do. Note the `case` statement that defines the LaborType field and the one in the `group by` clause must be identical.

The other `case` statement buried in the MaterialCost field allows you to count only the Install and Removal costs. The cast to Money isn't necessary. I just threw that in to show off. ;)

Check out the <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/920eb/31/0)</kbd>.

The test for `LaborTypes.TypeName IS NOT NULL` is not necessary because a NULL would not make it through the join.